# Is there any method or tool for comparing STIG versions?

Tags: java, stig

Is there an automated way to compare old STIGS to new STIGS? For example, if I'm using Java 7 and the newer version Java 8 comes out, I want to compare the two to see what's changed. Currently I'm doing this manually and it's very painful. Is there an automated way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but i figured i'd answer it anyway. There is a SaaS tool called [Vaulted](http://vaulted.io) (https://vaulted.io) that was released recently that allows you to compare DISA STIGs. It contains a library of all current STIGs and SRGs, and allows you to look at look versions of those STIGs/SRGs and compare them. You need a free account to do it, but if you're still interested it might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the only official option is to watch the "Quarterly Release Schedule and Summary" page and read each doc for changes.

https://public.cyber.mil/stigs/release-schedule/

Or to sign up for the mailing list

https://public.govdelivery.com/accounts/USDISA/subscriber/new?topic_id=USDISA_181